# Android Studio -error "unresolved class MyFirebaseMessagingService"

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I'm setting up Firebase on my app and I'm getting an error that's telling me something isn't declared as a class, but it is. The other solutions online have not solved my problem. I checked and the two classes that are supposedly not there are there when I search. I've screenshotted the classes where I search.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NBtX.jpg

Even when I fix the names it doesn't work.

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  package="com.example.leoconnelly.connexus">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

 <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/connexus_logo" 
  android:label="@string/app_name" 
 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/connexus_logo_round" android:supportsRtl="true" 
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"         android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HealthCenterListActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".HealthCenterSelectedActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MoreInfoActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RecordHealthInfo" />
    <activity android:name=".SelectCity"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" 
   android:value="AIzaSyCvjWU00ZJxl273Idt9h9fLbMJuG-Rfe6w"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="27.1.1" />

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.leoconnelly.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>



</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: please post your gradle file contents.

Comment: .MyFirebaseMessagingService is the path correct? I mean for MyFirebaseInstanceIDService your path is com.leoconnelly.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.